# EMM - Device Compliance Monitoring Report Is wrong

Tags: wso2-iot

I set policy to android devices on EMM, and the device which I enroll into EMM is violated but in Device Compliance Monitoring report, the status of device is Policy Compliance while in Devices Compliance Monitoring (Current Status: Active) its violated!

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

I think the problem is in status variable value in devices_complience.hbs, it was Policy Compliance, where this data is loaded from ?

How can I fix this issue?

More info:

wso2-emm version 1.1.0

server: win 7

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug
https://wso2.org/jira/browse/EMM-764

Data is getting form the module mdm-reports.js in emm. You can find that file from
https://github.com/wso2/product-emm/blob/master/modules/apps/emm/modules/mdm_reports.js

It uses SQL query to retrieve information form the database.

Comment: The status value stored in devices table is wrong, It is set to A which it should be PV. Where this value is set?